# foreign key removed on new/build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, instance-variables

hopefully someone can help me understand why this is happening.  i setup the following instances...

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@new_image = @product.images.new
```

when i debug `@new_image`, it correctly has the foreign key set.

```
--- !ruby/object:Image 
        attributes: 
          product_id: 1
```

however, when saving, the `product_id` was not being set.  that's when i noticed that also in that debug info, was this...

```
changed_attributes: 
  product_id:
```

basically nulling my foreign key.  same thing if i use build.  why isnt that instance not holding onto the foreign key?

**UPDATE:**
to make things simpler, even if i just output `debug Product.find(1).images.new` in my view, i get:

```
!ruby/object:ProductImage 
        attributes: 
          created_at: 
          product_id: 1
          updated_at: 
        attributes_cache: {}

        changed_attributes: 
          product_id: 
        destroyed: false
        marked_for_destruction: false
        new_record: true
        previously_changed: {}

        readonly: false
```

Comment: Can you post your full controller code that does the saving, and maybe the contents of your `Product` and `Image` models?

Comment: Okay, so where exactly are the very first two lines you posted being called?

Comment: in the show method of my products controller

Comment: Do does your Product#show method contain a form which then posts to Image#create?

Comment: yes, however i see the null product_id in `changed_attributes` before it ever reaches the form.  i eliminated the controllers from the equation entirely as shown in my last update.

Comment: `changed_attributes` shows what the values were **before** they were changed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, your product's `show` view contains a form to post to the `images` controller. When you create the `@new_image` variable based on `@product` in your view, it properly assigned the `product_id` to the image. However, this does NOT persist when you post your form.

You have two options. The simplest would be to just add a `<%= f.hidden_field :product_id %>` item to your form, that way the product_id actually gets posted to `Image#create`. Alternatively, you could create a nested resource and do a `<%= form_for [@product, @new_image] do |f| %>` instead of the `<%= form_for @new_image %>` that you're probably using right now, and then in your `create` method do:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@new_image = @product.images.new(params[:image])
```